# tracking pageviews without page reload

Tags: google-analytics

On my site I have search engine. If user select something from search filters there is page reload and URL is changing. GTM is fired anf all is ok.

When user chenge search criteria and makes next search URL is updatetd but GTM is not fired. This pageview is not registered. Is there gtm based solution for this problem_

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the fire pageview rule is set to URL match regex .* and it is fired once time a page is loaded. If you want to track it multiple times on one page (more virtual pages), I suggest you add firing rule "event equals virtualPageview" and add it into GA Pageview Tag as another firing condition. Then after new search result is loaded, send dataLayer.push({event:'virtualPageview'}).

### Summary:

1. Create new Firing Rule type Event - condition: event equals virtualPageview
2. Enhance tag UA Track Pageview in GTM with your new firing rule
3. Send dataLayer.push({event:'virtualPageview'}) as callback after new search results are loaded